# auth.token.email realtime database whith firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

is possible in realtime database rules
validate if email exist in Authentication?

because I login
at https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]
and get idToken to log in to the realtime database,
but I would like to know if there is a way to validate
if auth.token.email = authentication email and email enabled
this is a result of an idToken base64 decode:

I need to know if "email": "xx@xx.com" exists in Authentication user

```
{
 "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/xaxaxaxa",
 "aud": "xaxaxaxa",
 "auth_time": 1567541399,
 "user_id": "xxxxaxxaxaxaxaxaxax",
 "sub": "xaxaxaxaxaxaxaxa",
 "iat": 1567541399,
 "exp": 1567544999,
 "email": "xx@xx.com",
 "email_verified": false,
 "firebase": {
  "identities": {
   "email": ["xx@xx.com"]
  },
  "sign_in_provider": "password"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security rules can't check whether a certain email address exists. All they can do is read the claims in the token and act on that. But usually there's a `"email_verified"` claim in the token that you can use to ensure that the email address was verified:

```
"someNode": {
  ".write": "auth.token.email_verified === true"
}
```

Verification can happen either by the provider (such in the case of the Google and Facebook providers), or by your own code through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).